# Is there a function in R that allows be to replace NA with mean of row criteria?

Tags: r, replace, na

I have a tibble I am working with with NAs in a column. I want to replace the NAs (numeric column) with the mean of the column and queue_name column. For example, the NA for row two will be replaced by the mean where queue is "B". NA should be 150 for all queue B's with NA.

```
call_center_tbl <- tribble(~queue_name, ~talk_time,
        "A", 230,
        "B", "NA",
        "C", 150,
        "A", 200,
        "B", 100,
        "B", 200,
        "C", "NA")
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with data.table is the following. In your data, `talk_time` is in character. So I converted the column to numeric. Then, for each `queue_name`, I used `replace()` in order to replace NA with the average value of each group.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(call_center_tbl)[, talk_time := as.numeric(talk_time)][,
   talk_time :=  replace(talk_time,
                         list = which(is.na(talk_time)),
                         values = mean(talk_time, na.rm = TRUE)),
   by = queue_name][]

   queue_name talk_time
1:          A       230
2:          B       150
3:          C       150
4:          A       200
5:          B       100
6:          B       200
7:          C       150
```

You can use `nafill()` instead of `replace()`, if you want.

```
setDT(call_center_tbl)[, talk_time := as.numeric(talk_time)][,
                          talk_time := nafill(x = talk_time, fill = mean(talk_time, na.rm = TRUE)),
                                  by = queue_name][]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `ifelse` statement after having grouped your values based on "queue_name":

```r
library(dplyr)
call_center_tbl %>% 
  mutate(talk_time = as.numeric(talk_time)) %>% 
  group_by(queue_name) %>% 
  mutate(talk_time = ifelse(is.na(talk_time), mean(talk_time, na.rm =TRUE), talk_time))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   queue_name [3]
  queue_name talk_time
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 A                230
2 B                150
3 C                150
4 A                200
5 B                100
6 B                200
7 C                150
```

You can also use `replace_na`  function from `tidyr` package instead of `ifelse` statement:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
call_center_tbl %>% 
  mutate(talk_time = as.numeric(talk_time)) %>% 
  group_by(queue_name) %>% 
  mutate(talk_time = replace_na(talk_time, mean(talk_time, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: I did that and received got back a NaN instead of NA.

Comment: Weird... it works for me based on your example. Did you add `na.rm = TRUE` in the `mean` function ?

Comment: Hahaha !! I was going back to the example to see what I missed ! You totally got me on this one ;)